# Report junk function custom button Outlook Add-Ins

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Im pretty new to Outlook Add-Ins and Im currently working to create a custom Button that will mark selected Email as junk. I want to use the function that outlook already have to report junk and my custom button will just trigger this function. Is it possible to trigger this function?

Thank you

I was searching everywhere but didnt find a solution

Comment: Please share which API references you have checked so far.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use the function that outlook already have to report junk and my custom button will just trigger this function.

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. You can move the item to the `Junk Emails` folder programmatically by using the `Move` method.

Also you may try to execute the built-in ribbon button programmatically by using the [CommandBars.ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) method which executes the control identified by the `idMso` parameter. This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in `buttons`, `toggleButtons`, and `splitButtons`.